# Wordpress - base theme

Tags: wordpress

Am building some really custom sites (basic grid though) in wordpress. Are there any base themes that are good to use as a foundation to develop custom themes? I know there are quite a few out there and was just curious if there were any that were made specially for foundational purposes.

Comment: Questions like this should be sent to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: wow, ok did not know that even existed, doesn't look like it gets much hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thematic in my experience is unmatched as a base theme. I would recommend that. It already has bits of grid systems incorporated such as 960.gs and blueprint css... However, it does require an intermediate to advanced level of wordpress theming knowledge. I use it exclusively to build themes as it's so easy to override portions and is very seo friendly.

[Thematic website](http://themeshaper.com/)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am liking it so far, wish it was better documented, but so far so good. I will know more when I get into the hooks etc.

Comment: Glad you like it, yea more documentation would be nice. Very powerful theme. This might be helpful http://bluemandala.com/thematic/thematic-structure.html

Answer (score 1):

twentyten(the theme packaged with wordpress 3.0)  Is great for this.  You can learn a lot just from reading the comments in the code, and it has lots of features that you can customize for your own use.  Carrington jam is another that that I have seen used.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular one I know of is Thesis. It's not free, but I believe it's worth it.
http://diythemes.com/

Comment: Thematic is good too and has the advantage of being free. Another free option is to modify the default theme as jtmkrueger suggested. That's actually how I prefer to do things.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Apparantly child themes are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a theme generator to ease your work: http://www.lubith.com generates a TwentyTen based theme.